# Count the strings inside an excel column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an excel column as below:

[image: excel]

I need to find out the number of words in the column.

[image: mg]

Comment: How `DOG,CAT,ELEPHANT` count 4? It should be 3.

Comment: sorry my mistake

Comment: What are the odds there is a comma inside the substrings? E.g: `['A','B,C,D','E,F']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below formula-

```
=LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,",",""))+1
```

For dynamic spill array.

```
=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,LEN(x)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(x,",",""))+1))
```

[image]

Comment: Dada, `TEXTSPLIT()` was nice, why did you miss that

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya For older version support as well as, Jos Woolley already posted that.

Comment: Harun Dada, this will be short: `=MAP(A2:A3,LAMBDA(x,COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(x,","))))`

Comment: Alright dada. But you could have shown with `MAP()`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya The I would go with `=MAP(A2:A5,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(TEXTSPLIT(x,",")<>""))))`.

Comment: Dada, very good .

Answer (score 1):

If you have `TEXTSPLIT`:

`=COUNTA(TEXTSPLIT(A1,","))`